# how to add class to one div at a time Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animate.css

I want to use the jquery hover() to addClass("animated") to one element at a time NOT all elements with the class of .animated when the user hover on the parent element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".animateDiv").hover(function() {
      $('.animated').addClass('rubberBand');
    }, function() {
      $('.animated').removeClass('rubberBand');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="animateDiv">
  <h3 class="animated">Turn up summer.</h3>
  <h4>Box 1</h4>
</div>
    
<div class="animateDiv">
  <h3 class="animated">Turn up summer.</h3>
  <h4>Box 2</h4>
</div>

<div class="animateDiv">
  <h3 class="animated">Turn up summer.</h3>
  <h4>Box 3</h4>
</div>

<div class="animateDiv">
  <h3 class="animated">Turn up summer.</h3>
  <h4>Box 4</h4>
</div>
```

So again... how do I apply the class to only one box as at a time as the user hovers ?

Comment: `$('.animated', this).addClass('rubberBand');`

Comment: + better to just toggleClass();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can keep it short(er). There is no need to branch out hover unless you plan to have different in's and out's.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".animateDiv > .animated").hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass('rubberBand');});
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.animated', this).addClass('rubberBand');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(this)` scope will keep it limited to the hovered div. This also assumes that `.animated` is within `.animatedDiv`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".animateDiv").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.animated').addClass('rubberBand');
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.animated').removeClass('rubberBand');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
    <div class="animateDiv">
      <h3 class="animated">Turn up summer.</h3>
      <h4>Box 1</h4>
    </div>


    <div class="animateDiv">
      <h3 class="animated">Turn up summer.</h3>
      <h4>Box 2</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="animateDiv">
      <h3 class="animated">Turn up summer.</h3>
      <h4>Box 3</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="animateDiv">
      <h3 class="animated">Turn up summer.</h3>
      <h4>Box 4</h4>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.animateDiv').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.animated').addClass('rubberBand')
            $(this).siblings().find('.animated').removeClass('rubberBand')
        })
     });
    </script>
```